# why does isNaN always return true

Tags: javascript, nan, parseint

Having some trouble trying to validate strings that are numbers in JS. isNaN in particular seems to be misbehaving.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>No Quirks!</title>
</head>
     <body>
        <h1>JavaScript Test</h1>

        <button onclick="myNanIsTrue()">Is it a number?</button>

        <p id="writeToHTML"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myNanIsTrue() {
             var g = parseInt("40000000") + "<br />";
             var n = g;
             if (isNaN(g)){
                  g="moo!";
             }
             n += g + "<br />";
             document.getElementById("writeToHTML").innerHTML = n;
        }
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Tried a couple of permutations of this but it just doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Comment: Because `"40000000<br />"` isn't a number, but instead a string? `isNaN(parseInt("40000000"))` on the other hand returns `false` as expected.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thank you. Damn stay tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written:

```
var g = parseInt("40000000") + "<br />";
```

Therefore `g` is a string: `'40000000<br />'`.

`parseInt("40000000")` returns an integer, but then you append a string to it. Javascript implicitly converts the numer to a string, then concatenates them.

String's not a number, so `isNaN` (correctly) returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

isNaN means is Not a Number. This means that it is a function to check if your variable is not a number. 
In your case you are concatenating `<br>` to your integer, this converts your integer to a String.

```
/**
 * Created by jjansen on 10-Mar-15 4:38 PM.
 * stackoverflow
 */
var noNumber = parseInt("40000") + "<br>"; //this is now a String
var test = isNaN( noNumber ); //returns true
console.log("noNumber isNaN: " + test);
var number = parseInt("40000"); //this is a integer
test = isNaN( number );
console.log("number isNaN: " + test);
```

---

press f12 and copy this code in your console. You can now see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Because `g` is a string (you're concatenating a string, so it will be converted to one).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the value of `g` will always be a string due to the way you build it.

Whenever you add up a `String` and a `Number`, you will get a new `String` by concatenating the two values.

Therefore, in your code, `isNaN(g)` will always return `true`.